# Get class name of the element in selenium web driver java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium web driver right now i am facing the issue while getting the class name of an element
the html of the element look like

```
<input id="filter-colour-0237739001"><div class="detailbox detailbox-pattern unavailable-colour"><span></span><img src="//lp2.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/fabric/2014/9B57A69A-FD8D-4D79-9E92-8F5448566C51.jpg],type[FABRICSWATCH]&hmver=0&call=url[file:/product/main]" alt="" title="">
```

so i want to extract the class name which is class="detailbox detailbox-pattern unavailable-colour" by using selenium web driver.
I got the element by the below code

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.id("filter-colour-0237739001"));
```

now i want the class so can you please help me on this , i am okay with java script also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `getAttribute()`

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter-colour-0237739001']/../div"));
ele.getAttribute("class")
```

**EDIT** I guess you wanted the class of `div` so you should be using a selector pointing to div such as `//*[@id='filter-colour-0237739001']/../div` as xpath